# How to solve this equation using $ \log $?

Tags: logarithms

I am new to logarithms, and I came across this equation..

$$ \ (3)^{4x} - (3)^{(2x + \log_3(12))} +27 = 0 \ $$

I need a way to simply things as this seems very complex

Edit:

I tried $$ \ (3)^{4x} + 27 = (3)^{(2x + \log_3(12))}  \ $$

So $$ \ (3)^{4x} + 3^{3} = (3)^{(2x + \log_3(12))}  \ $$

Then, $$ \ log ((3)^{4x} + 3^{3}) = (log(3))(2x + \log_3(12)) \ $$

Comment: Solve for $y=9^x$. The equation written in terms of $y$ is $y^2-3^{\log_3(12)}y+27=0$. Or $y^2-12y+27=0$. You get that $(y-9)(y-3)=0$. From where either $9^x=y=9$ or $9^x=y=3$. So, either $x=1$ or $x=1/2$.

Comment: Hint: use the substitution $x=3^{2x}$ to get a quadratic. Also bear in mind: $a^{x+y}=a^xa^y$ and $a^{\log_a(x)}=x$ ($0<x$).

Comment: The method you're attempting won't get you very far as you've seen as you can't simplify the expression on the LHS easily.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was wanting

Comment: Is there any formula for $ \log(m+n) $ ?

Comment: @RaviPrakash no there isn't some commonly used identity for that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is solution of this equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348098/what-is-solution-of-this-equation)

Comment: @Shuri2060 Any uncommon identity?

Comment: @RaviPrakash I said 'commonly', just in case there actually are, but not that I know of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$3^{4x}-3^{2x}\cdot3^{\log_312}+3^3=0$$

$3^{\log_312}$ - is a basic logharithmic rule

then substitute

$3^{2x} = t$

and solve square equation that depends on $t$

I think you can finish it yourself :)